# subversion client encrypted password via gnome-keyring for ssh (only) client

Tags: svn, encryption, ssh, passwords, gnome

I want subversion to encrypt my passwords on a Fedora server without the gnome desktop running.  However I did start in the gnome GUI for a sanity test and did the normal mods to:

### ~/.subversion/config

```
password-stores = gnome-keyring
store-passwords = yes
```

### ~/.subversion/servers

```
[global]
store-passwords = yes
store-plaintext-passwords = no
```

Then I deleted the `~/.subversion/auth` dir, performed an svn operation and presto, password stored in the gnome-keyring and not plain-text.  Then I ssh'd to the same server and ran:

```
export `gnome-keyring-daemon`
```

which gave me a funny error:

`gnome-keyring-daemon: couldn't lookup ssh component setting: Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Not running within active session)gnome-keyring-daemon: couldn't lookup pkcs11 component setting: Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Not running within active session)`

At this point I'm stuck.  Only other thing I can say is that when the gnome desktop is running I can export `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-oCE5teZHWJ,guid=39013abab7d3f9e97422b8d94e45a9c2` on the ssh client and that works.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/186717/36198 has several good solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check here: http://technicalprose.blogspot.com/2011/06/using-subversion-with-gnome-keyring.html

Mark Bannister has good instructions and a great script that pulls it all together.